# Where does one find their own MSAL client-id

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I want to try the example JSFiddle with my own client credentials, but I don't know where to find my own client id to fill in the parameter for

```
<mgt-msal-provider client-id="what's_my_id">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a tutorial at the bottom of the [MSAL Provider documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/msal) underneath the **Creating an App/Client ID** section.

The quick start link will bring you to the [Quickstart: Register an application with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) documentation.